# how to calculate the time taken to get response from a service in iphone technology

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to measure the time taken to get response from a service call, do we have any tools to calculate or any classes in iphone sdk to calculate the response time

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use NSDate:

```
NSDate *start=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Start time %@", start);

[request startSynchronous];
```

and in the success/fail selector, call:

```
NSDate *end=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"End time %@", end);

double ellapsedSeconds= [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 startDate = [NSDate date];
```

here you call the webservice

```
NSTimeInterval startTime = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

this will give you the time interval.